# python import statements with two pythons installed

Tags: python

On my Windows 7 laptop I have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed, and I've been switching back and forth between them like `py -2 myscript.py` etc.

I explicitly installed a package called `pdfminer` by using `pip2` and I've verified that it's on my disk at `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pdfminer`

However, when I try to run a script I get an error:

```
> py -2 pdfminer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdfminer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\myprog\pdfminer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
ImportError: No module named pdfparser
```

The import statement is exactly as given in the PDFMiner documentation, and I even added the Python 2 scripts directory explicitly to the PATH just in case that would help, but it didn't (I actually think that's redundant because from printing out `sys.path` it seems it was already there):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\\")

from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
```

Within `site-packages\pdfminer` there is a file `pdfparser.py` and within it `class PDFParser(PSStackParser)`. The case doesn't match the import statement, but actually making the import statement lowercase to match the file also doesn't help.

I don't really see anything wrong here. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Could you verify one thing for me? Please try this command

Comment: C:\Python27\python.exe pdfminer.py

Comment: Same thing, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've called your own script `pdfminer.py` which is now shadowing the module you're trying to import. Rename your script.

You can see this in the traceback:

`File "C:\Users\me\Documents\myprog\pdfminer.py", line 4, in <module>`

That isn't the path that you installed the package on, but we can see that there is a file called `pdfminer`.

Comment: Oh man, that was it. I also had a directory named `pdfminer`, not sure which of the two was the cause but once I fixed both it started working. THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying which Python installation to use at the start of your programme, providing a link to the installation.

e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I am running Python with `py -2 myscript.py`. It is getting the right version of Python, I verified this by printing `sys.version`